# Somar itens dentro de um array

Tags: python

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
    soma_campos = null
    tabela = [
        ['A-B', 22, 0.045,  0.1,    0.005],
        ['A-C', 50, 0.020,  0.1,    0.002],
        ['A-D', 48, 0.021,  0.1,    0.002],
        ['A-E', 29, 0.034,  0.1,    0.003]
    ]
```

Como posso fazer pra que a variável `soma_campos` receba a soma de todos os segundos valores de cada array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só fazendo uma correção, isso que você criou na verdade é uma lista e não um array, a sintaxe para criar um array seria algo como `array([1, 2, 3])`, veja [aqui](https://www.pythoncentral.io/the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array/) uma explicação rápida das diferenças entre os dois.

Para pegar os valores que estão no segundo item de cada sublista, você pode usar o ***list comprehensions***, que "*fornece uma maneira concisa de criar listas*" (mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) e [aqui](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)). A sintaxe seria essa:

```
valores = [sub_lista[1] for sub_lista in tabela]
```

Esse código usando *list comprehensions* faz o equivalente a um for loop:

```
valores = []
for sub_lista in tabela:
    valores.append(sub_lista[1])
```

E para somar esses valores você pode usar a função `sum()`, passando diretamente a lista resultante de valores. O código final ficaria assim:

```
tabela = [
    ['A-B', 22, 0.045, 0.1, 0.005],
    ['A-C', 50, 0.020, 0.1, 0.002],
    ['A-D', 48, 0.021, 0.1, 0.002],
    ['A-E', 29, 0.034, 0.1, 0.003]
]
soma_campos = sum([sub_lista[1] for sub_lista in tabela])
print('Soma dos campos: ', soma_campos)
```

Veja um exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8XcDpe).

Comment: Eu acho que dá até pra tirar o `[]` e passar a comprehension direto: `soma_campos = sum(item[1] for item in tabela)`

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.
Desculpa a confusão, novato ainda. kk

Comment: Verdade @hkotsubo, dessa forma também funciona! Mas, por que será? Na documentação dá a entender que sempre tem que vir envolto com os `[]`.

Comment: Tranquilo @SergioSacchettiJunior! Eu mesmo não manjo basicamente nada de Python, mas fiz uma pesquisa para te responder e já aprendi algumas coisas! ;-)

Comment: Bom, eu ainda estou estudando Python e não sei todos os detalhes, mas ao tirar o `[]` a expressão se torna um [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Pelo que vi até agora, ela também é iterável (tal qual uma lista, por isso pode ser passada para `sum`), a diferença é que o generator é *lazy* (só processa os elementos quando requisitados, diferente da lista, que precisa ter todos os elementos criados). Se bem que para casos pequenos como esse não deve fazer diferença...